# (QGIS) How to improve Hillshade view of SRTM

Tags: dem

I've downloaded some DEMs using opentopography plug in. When I change the render type to hillshade and try to zoom in to actually be able to view anything I just get black lines with a grey background.

Is there anyway to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What is the projection system of your data?

Comment: how did you create the hill shades?

Comment: If you create a hillshade using one of the Processing hillshade tools (the gdal section has one that I typically used but there is another in the raster terrain analysis group) do you get something that you expected instead of your image?

Comment: Make sure your Resampling in the Symbology tab of layer styling isnt set to Nearest Neighbor

Comment: I have changed the resampling to nearest neighbor but it still isn't great when zoomed it. I'm guessing that with the data I have that it's as good as it gets?